# Can't update an image source on mouseover

Tags: wpf, data-binding

The goal is to change the grid background color, the TextBlock color and the image when the mouse is over the grid row.
I don't understand why the following code doesn't work:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="mystyle">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=mygrid, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="blue" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="image2.png" />
          </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="mygrid" Style="{StaticResource mystyle}">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <Image Source="image1.png" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

It works fine for the grid and textblock color but not for the image...
 It behaves like the setter for Image.Source was not here... Any idea?

Comment: Besides the problem addressed in the duplicate question, your expectation is also wrong. You can't have a single Style applied to a Grid that magically changes the property of any child elements. `Property="Image.Source"` is not a valid target property path, although there is an Image child element. The `Image` part of that property path optionally addresses the class of the object where you apply a Style without a TargetType, or it addresses the class where an attached property like `TextBlock.FontSize` is declared.

Comment: In short, you need a distinct Style for the Image element, which has a Setter for the default value of the Source property, and a DataTrigger with a Setter for some other value.

Comment: Thank you @Clemens for these useful comments. Now it works but not in the expected way yet. The image changes on mouseover but I would like it to change when the mouse is over the entire row. Any advice? Thx

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate.triggers